# SwiperJS Slider becomes flat after loading

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

So, I tried putting a preloader for one of my websites today.

The problem is with the swiper slider(with 3D Coverflow Effect). When the page loads swiper slider becomes flat and if I resize my browser it returns to the normal 3D view.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $(".loader").fadeOut(2000);
  $(".content-sector").fadeIn(2000);
});

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  effect: 'coverflow',
  grabCursor: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  coverflowEffect: {
    rotate: 30,
    stretch: 0,
    depth: 300,
    modifier: 1,
    slideShadows: true,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
});
```

```css
.content-sector{
  display: none;
}            
.card-custom {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.swiper-slide {
    width: 400px;
}

/* Try changing the output window size*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.4.5/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.4.5/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a2/dc/96/a2dc9668f2cf170fe3efeb263128b0e7.gif" alt="" style="width:100%;">
</div>
<div class="content-sector">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="card card-custom">
            <div class="sliderText bg-dark">
              <img src="img/default.png" class="rounded-circle shadow" width="180" height="180" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h4>Person 1</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis quisquam at voluptatum, voluptatibus sequi earum? Similique officia atque vero impedit.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-custom">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="card card-custom">
            <div class="sliderText bg-dark">
              <img src="img/default.png" class="rounded-circle shadow" width="180" height="180" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h4>Person 1</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis quisquam at voluptatum, voluptatibus sequi earum? Similique officia atque vero impedit.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-custom">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="card card-custom">
            <div class="sliderText bg-dark">
              <img src="img/default.png" class="rounded-circle shadow" width="180" height="180" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h4>Person 1</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis quisquam at voluptatum, voluptatibus sequi earum? Similique officia atque vero impedit.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-custom">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="card card-custom">
            <div class="sliderText bg-dark">
              <img src="img/default.png" class="rounded-circle shadow" width="180" height="180" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h4>Person 1</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis quisquam at voluptatum, voluptatibus sequi earum? Similique officia atque vero impedit.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-custom">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- HTML Code

```
<div class="loader">
    <img src="img1.gif" alt="">
</div>
<div class="content-sector">
    ---Whole page content in here---
</div>
```

- JS part(jquery-3.5.1.min.js)

```
<script>
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $(".loader").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".content-sector").fadeIn(1000);
    });
</script>
```

- A working example
  [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/re4nightwing/8tr3Lzgo/5/)

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: create minimum reproducable example of the your issue somewhere please

Comment: @IvanKaraman I added an example link to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue related to some conflict you made.

On load `.content-sector` display is `none` (Swiper inside)

```
.content-sector{
  display: none;
}
```

This scenario "breaks" swiper Core `cube` calculations.
Why? (You should open GitHub issue an ask/report).

For now remove `display: none;` (Or change to display: none; by code after swiper loads).

Next looks like Jquery animations also break the layout.

If you want to create a `fade-in` effect for the swiper - for now, use white overlay above the content.

Snippet:

```js
/* Initialize Swiper */
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  effect: 'coverflow',
  grabCursor: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  coverflowEffect: {
    rotate: 30,
    stretch: 0,
    depth: 300,
    modifier: 1,
    slideShadows: true,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
});

/* on load */
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $(".loader").fadeOut(2000);
  $(".content-sector").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

```css
   
.card-custom {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.swiper-slide {
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.4.5/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.4.5/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a2/dc/96/a2dc9668f2cf170fe3efeb263128b0e7.gif" alt="" style="width:100%;">
</div>
<div class="content-sector">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="card card-custom">
            <div class="sliderText bg-dark">
              <img src="img/default.png" class="rounded-circle shadow" width="180" height="180" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h4>Person 1</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis quisquam at voluptatum, voluptatibus sequi earum? Similique officia atque vero impedit.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-custom">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="card card-custom">
            <div class="sliderText bg-dark">
              <img src="img/default.png" class="rounded-circle shadow" width="180" height="180" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h4>Person 1</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis quisquam at voluptatum, voluptatibus sequi earum? Similique officia atque vero impedit.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-custom">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="card card-custom">
            <div class="sliderText bg-dark">
              <img src="img/default.png" class="rounded-circle shadow" width="180" height="180" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h4>Person 1</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis quisquam at voluptatum, voluptatibus sequi earum? Similique officia atque vero impedit.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-custom">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="card card-custom">
            <div class="sliderText bg-dark">
              <img src="img/default.png" class="rounded-circle shadow" width="180" height="180" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h4>Person 1</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Corporis quisquam at voluptatum, voluptatibus sequi earum? Similique officia atque vero impedit.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-custom">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```